# how to get all tags inside htmltext in a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have webpage html source inside a `textarea` having `id="textArea1"`.

This Html code is containing some `"p"` tags.
I want to get list of all p tags which lie in textArea of above code

Comment: Welcome to SO.. "I want to get list of all p tags" -- what list..? can you be more specific...?

Comment: By list mean: how much "p" tags are there and somehow be able to get their inner text by some query  ('p')[0] , [1] like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get list of all p tags

The text inside a `<textarea>` is a string, not sure what exactly you mean by `list` if you want substrings inside `<p>`  you can use `split()` function...

```
$('#textArea1').change(function(){ // or any other event you want
 var text= $(this).val();
 var count= text.split('<p>').length-1;
 console.log(count);
});
```

check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/EW53d/)

**Update:**

as per comment, you can get the text inside occurances of `<p></p>` (assuming the html string inside `textarea` is in a valid format) as follows:

```
$('#textArea1').change(function(){
 var text= $(this).val();
 var strings= text.split('<p>');
 for(i=1;i<strings.length;i++){
    strings[i]= strings[i].split('</p>')[0];
    console.log(strings[i]);
 }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/EW53d/7/)

Comment: I am getting this error : Cannot read property 'split' of undefined 
I have included jquery-1.10.1.min.js
and this function is under document.ready

Comment: @user3552055 that's not because whatever the string you're trying to split is more than empty, the string is not assigned to the variable (`undefined`)
check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/EW53d/7/) it prints the strings inside <p></p>(assuming the html inside is in valid format) you can access each string like strings[0], strings[1] etc..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot count the paragraph elements or the value inside the `textarea` as you could find them inside a seperate element. Textarea is not meant for such purpose.

You can try counting all the `p` tags inside some other element like a seperate div which gets populated by the textarea value.

```
$('#textArea1').keyup(function () {
   $('div').html($(this).val());
   var totalPs = 0;
   $('div').find('p').each(function () {
     totalPs++;
   });
});
```

This would try counting the p elements.

It would:

1. Handle an event on the textarea with the id `textArea`.
2. Append the value of the textarea to the element (div here).
3. Create a variable with value 0.
4. Find `p` elements inside the element and then iterate it n times; n would be the number of paragraph elements.
5. Increment the value.

You can use the value as the result and then get that inside the document or in the console.

Comment: It always give me 0 count
i.e  $('#textArea1').find('p').each(function () {
                totalPs++;
            });

Comment: That is because you're just searching for the value inside the textarea. Try splitting the value, use this: `totalPs = $(this).val().split('<p>').length` to get the number of the `p` elements inside the textarea...@user3552055

Comment: Which is the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23179480/2333214) i posted 10 minutes ago... ;)